# fastest way to read data from a huge excel file in java

Tags: java, excel

I have an excel file downloaded from SAP. I want to read particular columns from that file, create a json object from it and then render it on a jsp. what would be the fastest way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open a huge excel file efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46373895/how-to-open-a-huge-excel-file-efficiently) - check the Java Answers, it is fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fond of [JExcel](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) for it's simplicity, but it loads the entire spreadsheet into memory. If you have enough memory for this, I'd use it.

If you don't have sufficient memory to read the entire file into memory, then you'll probably want to use the streaming capabilities of [POI-XSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/)

Answer (score 0):

i'am oftenly use talend http://www.talend.com/products/talend-open-studio. as far as i try it, you can generate a web service that meets your needs, from excel convert to json and certain data.