# Skip columns while reading big excel file using Open Xml Sax approach

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, sax

I am reading several medium sized excel files, approximately 50 columns x 500 rows. The problem is that some formatting is dragged until column `XFD`, that is column number `16384=2^16/4` if my math is correct. With OleDb this does not cause any problems as the following query let me select only a subset of the total spreadsheet without huge performance loss caused by the remaining columns

```
SELECT * FROM [SheetNameA1:BC500]
```

This takes around 3 seconds. The problem with OleDb is that it requires windows and a file at a disk, both of these causes some trouble with our cloud infrastructure and we would like to use OpenXml instead. OpenXml can be used with DOM-approach or SAX-approach. The first is a show stopper as a call to `Worksheet` getter at `WorksheetPart` loads the whole xml with all columns taking around 10 seconds.

Using the SAX approach to navigate the XML gives me the 5 methods for navigating a `OpenXmlReader`: `LoadCurrentElement`, `Read`, `ReadFirstChild`, `ReadNextSibling` and `Skip`. Using these I can:

- use `Read` until I am hitting the `Row` elements
- use `ReadFirstChild` to hit first `Cell` element and `ReadNextSibling` to read remaining and load them using `LoadCurrentElement` until column BC
- use `ReadNextSibling` until the whole `Row` is read (ignoring content, i.e. no call to `LoadCurrentElement`)

The performance loss is in the last step. How can I make the reader jump to the next row without looping through all the cells.

I think the key might be to use `Skip` to loop over all children. The problem is that I need to be at Row-element to skip all Cell elements and there is no way to "rewind".

Here is an example I made to illustrate the problem. The excel file is simply marked with `x` in the range A1:XFD500. And here are the messures from while-time and load-time:

[image]

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

using (var file = File.Open("testfile.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(file, false);

    var workbookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
    var sheet = doc
        .WorkbookPart
        .Workbook
        .Descendants<Sheet>()
        .First(s => s.Name == "sheetName");

    var worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)doc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id);

    OpenXmlReader reader = OpenXmlReader.Create(worksheetPart);
    Dictionary<int, string> sharedStringCache = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    var rows = new List<List<object>>();

    int i = 0;
    foreach (var el in workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements)
    {
        sharedStringCache.Add(i++, el.InnerText);
    }

    TimeSpan whileTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
    TimeSpan loadTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
    var stopwatch1 = new Stopwatch();
    var stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();

    int lastColumnWithData = 50;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.ElementType == typeof(Row))
        {
            reader.ReadFirstChild();
            List<object> cells = new List<object>();
            do
            {
                if (reader.ElementType == typeof(Cell))
                {
                    stopwatch2.Restart();
                    Cell c = (Cell)reader.LoadCurrentElement();
                    loadTime += stopwatch2.Elapsed;

                    var columnLetters = Regex.Replace(c.CellReference, @"[\d]", string.Empty).ToUpper();
                    var columnIndex = NumberFromExcelColumn(columnLetters);
                    var rowIndex = int.Parse(Regex.Replace(c.CellReference, @"[^\d]", string.Empty).ToUpper());

                    if (columnIndex > lastColumnWithData)
                    {
                        stopwatch1.Restart();
                        while (reader.ReadNextSibling()) {}
                        whileTime += stopwatch1.Elapsed;
                        break;
                    }

                    object value;

                    switch (c.DataType?.Value)
                    {
                        case CellValues.Boolean:
                            value = bool.Parse(c.CellValue.InnerText);
                            break;
                        case CellValues.Date:
                            value = DateTime.Parse(c.CellValue.InnerText);
                            break;
                        case CellValues.Number:
                            value = double.Parse(c.CellValue.InnerText);
                            break;
                        case CellValues.InlineString:
                        case CellValues.String:
                            value = c.CellValue.InnerText;
                            break;
                        case CellValues.SharedString:
                            value = sharedStringCache[int.Parse(c.CellValue.InnerText)];
                            break;
                        default:
                            value = c.CellValue.InnerText;
                            break;
                    }

                    if (value != null)
                        cells.Add(value);
                }

            } while (reader.ReadNextSibling());

            if (cells.Any())
                rows.Add(cells);
        }
    }
}

static int NumberFromExcelColumn(string column)
{
    int retVal = 0;
    string col = column.ToUpper();
    for (int iChar = col.Length - 1; iChar >= 0; iChar--)
    {
        char colPiece = col[iChar];
        int colNum = colPiece - 64;
        retVal = retVal + colNum * (int)Math.Pow(26, col.Length - (iChar + 1));
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

made using examples from:

[How to open a huge excel file efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46373895/how-to-open-a-huge-excel-file-efficiently/46423255#)

[Fastest function to generate Excel column letters in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837155/fastest-function-to-generate-excel-column-letters-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

The Skip() function will skip the child elements of the current node.

If the current loaded element is the parent Row this can be used.

For the example above it would be simpler break out of the do while loop when the count is reached. Using break will skip any remaining siblings and move to the next element that is a typeof row.

```
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.ElementType == typeof(Row))
                {
                    reader.ReadFirstChild();

                    int lastColumnWithData = 50;
                    int columnCount = 0;

                    do
                    {
                        if (reader.ElementType == typeof(Cell))
                        {
                            columnCount += 1;
                        }
                    } while (reader.ReadNextSibling() && columnCount <= lastColumnWithData);
                }
                
            }
```

or to move to the last child element before exiting iteration, try the following.

```
                  do
                    {

                        if (reader.ElementType == typeof(Cell))
                        {
                            columnCount += 1;
                            if (columnCount > lastColumnWithData)
                            {
                                // skip to last element
                                while (reader.ReadNextSibling() && !reader.IsEndElement)
                                {
                                };
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    } while (reader.ReadNextSibling());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @nimblebit, you are writing

> If the current loaded element is the parent Row this can be used.

In the state where I am iterating through cells and have just discovered that the cell I have read was the last, how do I make the cell's parent row "the current loaded element"?

> Using break will skip any remaining siblings and move to the next element that is a typeof row.

Will we not arrive at `while (reader.Read())` when we `break` causing all remaining cell to be read with a performance cost before we arrive at the next row?