# C# Function uses a lot of memory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, parallel-processing, parallel.for

I use ASP.NET Core 6 MVC with `ClosedXML.Excel` reader from Excel via `parallel.For`, but this function eats more than 1.5 Gb of Ram memory.

[Image how much memory uses the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lt1e0.png)

```
public static void ReadFile(IFormFile MyFileCollection)
{
        IFormFile MyFile;
        int FileLen;
        System.IO.Stream MyStream;

        MyFile = MyFileCollection;
        FileLen = Convert.ToInt32(MyFile.Length);
        byte[] input = new byte[FileLen];

        if (MyFile.FileName.Contains('~'))
        { 
            NameOfUpload = MyFile.FileName.Split('~')[1].Split('.')[0]; 
        }

        // Initialize the stream.
        MyStream = MyFile.OpenReadStream();

        // Read the file into the byte array.
        MyStream.Read(input, 0, FileLen);
        bool _FindedHead = false;

        var workbook = new XLWorkbook(MyStream, XLEventTracking.Disabled);
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheet(1);

        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(MyStream))
        {
            var result = reader.AsDataSet();
            DataSet _DtSet = reader.AsDataSet();
            DataTable dataTable = _DtSet.Tables[0];
            DataView _Workscheet_DataViewData = dataTable.AsDataView();

            var rows = dataTable.Rows.Count;
            int _GlobalRow_Count = dataTable.Rows.Count;
            string[,] _Data_ERS = new string[_GlobalRow_Count + 10, 3];
            int _StartPosition = 1;

            int localSizes = dataTable.Rows.Count;
            string[] _Number_Nakladnoi = new string[localSizes];
            string[] _NumberOrderOf_Sender = new string[localSizes];
            string[] _Partiya = new string[localSizes];
            string[] _NomerRZ = new string[localSizes];
            int[] _PlaceCount = new int[localSizes];
            string[] _MethodDelivery = new string[localSizes];
            string[] _TypeOf_delivery = new string[localSizes];
            string[] _CityDelivery = new string[localSizes];
            string[] _PVZ_Target = new string[localSizes];
            string[] _Kladr_PointDelivery = new string[localSizes];
            DateTime[] _DateFaktDelivery = new DateTime[localSizes];
            string[] _CargoState = new string[localSizes];
            string[] _ReasonDontArrive = new string[localSizes];
            double[] _WeightBySize = new double[localSizes];
            double[] _WeightFakt = new double[localSizes];
            double[] _COD = new double[localSizes];
            string[] _TypeOfPay = new string[localSizes];
            //string[] _LstERs = new string[localSizes];
            string[] _TempCheck = new string[localSizes];

            for (int z = 1; z < dataTable.Rows.Count; z++)
            {
                var _Parametr_Row = worksheet.Row(z);
                _Number_Nakladnoi[z] = _Parametr_Row.Cell(1).GetValue<string>().ToString().Trim();

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Number_Nakladnoi[z]))
                { 
                    continue; 
                }

                if (_Number_Nakladnoi[z].ToLower() == "номер посылки")
                { 
                    _FindedHead = true; _StartPosition = z + 1; 
                    break; 
                }

                if (!_FindedHead)
                { 
                    continue; 
                }
            }

            ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
            options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 150;

            ConcurrentBag<DataFromFile> ConCurentCollection = new ConcurrentBag<DataFromFile>();
            ConcurrentBag<int> ConCurentTest = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
            DataFromFile[] _BagCollectionArray = new DataFromFile[dataTable.Rows.Count];

            var resultParallel = Parallel.For(_StartPosition, dataTable.Rows.Count, options, (i, state) =>
            {
                var _Parametr_Row = worksheet.Row(i).Cell(4).CachedValue;

                _Number_Nakladnoi[i] = worksheet.Row(i).Cell(1).GetValue<string>().ToString().Trim(); //
                _NumberOrderOf_Sender[i] = worksheet.Row(i).Cell(2).GetValue<string>().ToString().Trim(); //
                _Partiya[i] = worksheet.Row(i).Cell(4).CachedValue.ToString();// worksheet.Row(i).Cell(4).GetValue<string>(); //
                _NomerRZ[i] = worksheet.Row(i).Cell(5).GetValue<string>().ToString().Trim(); //
                _PlaceCount[i] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(worksheet.Row(i).Cell(6).GetValue<string>().ToString()) ? 0 : worksheet.Row(i).Cell(6).GetValue<int>(); //
                _MethodDelivery[i] = worksheet.Row(i).Cell(7).GetValue<string>().ToString().Trim(); //
                _TypeOf_delivery[i] = worksheet.Row(i).Cell(8).GetValue<string>().ToString().Trim();
                _CityDelivery[i] = addresses.GetCorrectCityName(worksheet.Row(i).Cell(10).GetValue<string>().ToString().Trim()); //The city Name
                _PVZ_Target[i] = worksheet.Row(i).Cell(11).GetValue<string>().ToString().Trim();
                _Kladr_PointDelivery[i] = worksheet.Row(i).Cell(12).GetValue<string>().ToString().Trim(); //

                _DateFaktDelivery[i] = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(worksheet.Row(i).Cell(15).GetValue<string>().ToString().Trim()) ? SystemClass.GetDateTimeFromString(worksheet.Row(i).Cell(15).GetValue<string>()) : SystemClass.GetDateTimeFromString(worksheet.Row(i).Cell(13).GetValue<string>()); //
                _CargoState[i] = worksheet.Row(i).Cell(18).GetValue<string>().ToString().Trim();
                _ReasonDontArrive[i] = worksheet.Row(i).Cell(19).GetValue<string>().ToString().Trim();

                _WeightBySize[i] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(worksheet.Row(i).Cell(20).GetValue<string>().ToString()) ? 0 : worksheet.Row(i).Cell(20).GetValue<double>();
                _WeightFakt[i] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(worksheet.Row(i).Cell(21).GetValue<string>().ToString()) ? 0 : worksheet.Row(i).Cell(21).GetValue<double>();
                _COD[i] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(worksheet.Row(i).Cell(23).GetValue<string>().ToString()) ? 0 : worksheet.Row(i).Cell(23).GetValue<double>();

                _BagCollectionArray[i] = new DataFromFile
                {
                    _Number_Nakladnoi = _Number_Nakladnoi[i],
                    _NumberOrderOf_Sender = _NumberOrderOf_Sender[i],
                    _Partiya = _Partiya[i],
                    _NomerRZ = _NomerRZ[i],
                    _PlaceCount = _PlaceCount[i],
                    _MethodDelivery = _MethodDelivery[i],
                    _TypeOf_delivery = _TypeOf_delivery[i],
                    _CityDelivery = _CityDelivery[i],
                    _PVZ_Target = _PVZ_Target[i],
                    _Kladr_PointDelivery = _Kladr_PointDelivery[i],
                    _DateFaktDelivery = _DateFaktDelivery[i],
                    _CargoState = _CargoState[i],
                    _ReasonDontArrive = _ReasonDontArrive[i],
                    _WeightBySize = _WeightBySize[i],
                    _WeightFakt = _WeightFakt[i],
                    _COD = _COD[i]
                };

                ConCurentCollection.Add(AddNewElement(_BagCollectionArray[i]));
                ConCurentTest.Add(i);
            });
        }

        MyStream.Close();
        worksheet.Delete();
        workbook.Dispose();
}
```

I tried to dispose everything, but everything looks like before.
Maybe I forget something or do something wrong.

I try to dispose `MyStream`, workbook, worksheet - but there is no result in the usage of memory.

I try reduce code and find out that the problem is on ClosedXML. I have tried many approaches to release resources but nothing help me.
I also tried use not static function, objects and GC.

`GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); GC.Collect();`

Maybe somebody have an Idea about how to dispose ClosedXML? Or maybe I do something wrong

Comment: Using available memory is not per se a problem. Or do you get an OutOfMemoryException? Or any other problem?

Comment: Now everything is ok, but I really worry about when I release it to server - this may be caused OutOfMemoryException

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, but if I close as duplicate it will close your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46373895/495455

Comment: Unfortunately no, My files open very fast everything works very fast (about 20 seconds) with 40 000 rows. I worry about use this approach in release version. I mean If forget something to release then not used memory may accrue.

Comment: Using many arrays with the same element count, sounds like a list of structs/classes/records..

Comment: Check how many rows are actually in your DataTable. I once made the mistake of every row from the file instead of only used rows (so instead of 400 it was a few million rows in my case).

Comment: Yes, you're right I paid attention to it too) but everything is ok. Like I understand the problem is in ClosedXML because it is not dispose. I tried update library but it's still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for everybody. Last time I updated ClosedXML and continue use

```
GC.Collect(); 
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

After that memory disposed. I don't know why but in my previous version this approach doesn't work.
Thank you again.
My current version ClosedXML - 0.97.0
[Result work for 14 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl6br.jpg)

I added screen how it works more than 14 days and uses less 417 Mb.

Answer (score 2):

Something that will help slightly (though won't make a massive difference) is to change:

```
if (_Number_Nakladnoi[z].ToLower() == "номер посылки")
```

to:

```
string.Equals(_Number_Nakladnoi[z], "номер посылки",
     StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

This would help reduce allocations.

Also, is there a need to create so many arrays instead of putting all your variables in a class/struct and have just one?

Comment: You're right. it will be better to use class. I will change it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

static objects remains in memory and never be collected.
one of reasons that this method eats memory is for 'static'.

read this for more info:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/common-memory-leaks-in-c-sharp/

Comment: I haven't heard about this, I'm going to change it. Thanks :)

Comment: I tried to use not static method, unfortunately result is the same. Using memory 1.7 Gb for this function and do not release after reading

Comment: another solution is to avoid global variables. maybe you are setting a huge value to your global variable. try removing them may help to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: also you can write your code in 'try/catch' and then in 'finally' dispose you disposable objects. by this you ensure that your streaming objects are disposed even when getting error

Comment: Thank you for your message.  I tried [try. catch, finally]. But the volume of used memory is till the same

Answer (score -1):

Try reducing reference types objects using, for example, structs

Comment: More in detail explanation would help OP and future users who will have similar problem, can you support your answer with more urls for op to use as a reference ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a using statement here to get the ram back

```
using(MyStream=MyFile.OpenReadStream()){
//Here you put the the code until 
//MyStream.Close();
}
worksheet.Delete
workbook.Dispose
```

Because the Files and FileStream are not in .Net-Framework they can't be collected by the Garbage collector. By using using(){} it become part of .Net-Framework for this Code-Block and can be collected by the Garbage collector